# AdonisJS app style missing or not working after deployment in Heroku

Tags: css, heroku, deployment, adonis.js

Basically i deployed a new AdonisJS app to Heroku, and the app itself works fine, all the migrations and functions of each controller, model and view work fine, the issue is that the style of the page, the size and the CSS are not showing or working properly. From what i searched, i need to use something called CDN and upload my styles there, but im kinda new in deploying apps, so i wondered if there was any other way to make the styles of the page show properly? I'll annex below the comparisson between the app running locally and the app deployed in heroku.

The first screenshot is from the app runnig locally on my laptop, the one below it is the app deployed on heroku

Any help or insight would be very appreciated, thanks for your time.

[image: App running locally]

[image: App deployed in Heroku]

Comment: Can you share your html code for script import?

Comment: Could you share the errors on browser console when you open heroku app